# Oracle VARCHAR (15 BYTE) to MS SQL Server 2014 DATA TYPES

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, types, sqldatatypes

I am creating multiple tables in MS SQL SERVER 2014 to that will receive data from an Oracle server. Some of the data types that are coming over from Oracle are set to VARCHAR2 (15 BYTE), VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) ETC....

I need to know what I should set my data types too in the MS SQL SERVER tables.

```
ITEM_NO             VARCHAR(15 BYTE)
UNIT_OF_MEASURE     CHAR(2 BYTE)
PARTNER_SKU         VARCHAR(15 BYTE)
UPC                 CHAR(12 BYTE)
ITEM_DESC           VARCHAR(60 BYTE)
ALT_ITEM_NO         VARCHAR(15 BYTE)
```

Comment: Just drop the `byte` and use `varchar()` and `char()`.

Comment: i.e. remove " BYTE" from varchar(15 byte) result: varchar(15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously stated in the comments above by @Gordon Linoff and @user2067753 in SQL Server you do not need to define the word `BYTE` when specifying data types in SQL Server. So for your declared fields above:

```
ITEM_NO             VARCHAR(15)
UNIT_OF_MEASURE     CHAR(2)
PARTNER_SKU         VARCHAR(15)
UPC                 CHAR(12)
ITEM_DESC           VARCHAR(60)
ALT_ITEM_NO         VARCHAR(15)
```

MSDN has many articles which you might also find helpful:

- [Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187752.aspx)
- [Creating Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174979.aspx)

You also might find these documents quite useful as it compares both Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle and documents a load of the differences:

- [From Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/doc/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm)
- [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151817.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Byte in Oracle is optional, Just used to enforce the size to be specific number of bytes rather than the length of the varchar value. There is no equivalent in SQL Server